# Steps to install Apache Tomcat on Linux server

Tags: linux, tomcat, installation

This may sound childish, but can anyone tell me step by step process to install apache tomcat on my linux server. I am a beginner and i am installing the apache for the first time to test my site.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to install it and test, just wget the binary, extract it and setup the environment variables.
There are several links which shows the steps. Take a look at this one:
http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-linux

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and perhaps the best way is to install through apt-get use:-

sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-docs tomcat7-examples tomcat7-admin

To access it go to browser

localhost:8080

In command Line we can use 
sudo service tomcat7 stop
sudo service tomcat7 start
sudo service tomcat7 restart

Answer (score 0):

Hoping it will help some one if not to OP!

Recently implemented apache-tomcat installation and configured it as a `systemd` service on all RHEL 7 servers.

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: servers
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Download tomcat version 8.5 using get-url
      get_url: url=https://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.38/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.38.zip dest=/opt/tomcat checksum="sha512:c60fdf7d4fc637cbdace5133b16c21e19a5c851436e360bd5284d9a3954d36f26d134086e66718420de2ebb457d65b6c9d248ba42bba03b5ea39729bae18e7b5"

    - name: unzip the tomcat file.
      unarchive: src=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.38.zip dest=/opt/tomcat owner=tomcat  group=tomcat mode='700'       ##make sure destination folder exists

    - name: create a softlink to /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.38
      file: src=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.38 dest=/opt/tomcat8 state=link 

    - name: Give execution rights to all the files in the bin directory
      file: path=/opt/tomcat8/bin mode='744' recurse=yes state=directory

    - name: Create tomcat.service file                  ## This is required to configure tomcat as a service in systemd
      file: path=/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat.service  state=touch

    - name: append the content to tomcat.service file
      blockinfile: 
        path: /usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat.service
        block: |
          [Unit]
          Description=Tomcat
          After=syslog.target network.target

          [Service]
          Type=forking

          User=tomcat
          Group=tomcat

          ExecStart=/opt/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh start
          ExecStop=/opt/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh stop

          [Install]
          WantedBy=multi-user.target


    - name: Reload the systemd configuration so that it will detect the new service file
      systemd: name=tomcat daemon_reload=yes enabled=yes state=started
```